# How to pass AWS CLI parameters as variables in Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have a AWS CLI command to download some files from my S3 bucket but I wanted to pass parameters and their values in from PowerShell variables. Is this possible?

This works:

```
$filterInclude = "7012*"
$results = aws s3 cp $bucketPath $destinationDir --recursive --exclude $filterExclude --include $filterInclude
```

But I wanted something like:

```
$filterInclude = "7012*"
$includeCom = "--include \`"$($filterInclude)\`""
$results = aws s3 cp $bucketPath $destinationDir --recursive --exclude $filterExclude "$($includeCom)"
```

The result I get is:
Unknown options: --include "7012*"

Comment: Can you try with --debug and see what it actually resolves to?

Comment: If you are already in PowerShell, why not use Read-S3Object from the AWS Tools for PowerShell? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Read-S3Object.html&tocid=Read-S3Object